# Creating Onboarding Pages - React Native

Tags: react-native, mobile, expo, react-navigation

I am creating an app in react native using expo and am having some trouble with the onboarding part of it.

My current code below in my App.js file goes straight to the homepage, skipping the whole onBoarding/introduction pages of the app.

How can I fix this?

```
  const [firstLaunch, setFirstLaunch] = useState(false);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    checkFirstLaunch();
  }, []);

  const checkFirstLaunch = async () => {
    const hasLaunched = await AsyncStorage.getItem('hasLaunched');
    if (hasLaunched === null) {
      await AsyncStorage.setItem('hasLaunched', 'true');
      setFirstLaunch(true);
    } else {
      setFirstLaunch(false);
    }
    setIsLoading(false);
  };

  if (isLoading) {
    return (
       <ActivityIndicator />
    );
  }

  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator screenOptions={{ headerShown: false }}>
        {firstLaunch ? (
          <>
            <Stack.Screen name='selectLanguage' component={selectLanguage}/>
            <Stack.Screen name='setLocation' component={setLocation} />
            <Stack.Screen name='enableNotifications' component={enableNotifications} />
              </>
          ) : (
            <Stack.Screen name='HomePage' component={HomePage} />
          )}
          </Stack.Navigator>
        </NavigationContainer>
      );
    };
```